# How to get the IP address from the preferred parent of a certain node in Contiki RPL classic

Tags: routes, contiki

Hello everyone and thank you in advance for the attention.

I would like to obtain, in a certain node, the **IP Address** of it's certain **preferred parent**. I am using the Contiki-3.x RPL implementation, which is the same as **RPL-Classic** found in **Contiki-NG.**

In the old implementation, from Contiki-2.6, the **rpl_parent_t struct** had a field named **addr** so I could just use the following sample:

```
PRINT6ADDR(&instance_table[i].dag_table[j].preferred_parent->addr);
```

however, at this moment, the rpl_parent_t struct does not have the addr anymore. I am finding it hard to understand how should I adapt this code sample.

Anyone has a hint for me?

Thank for the attention.
Kind regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Contiki 3.x, use the function `rpl_get_parent_ipaddr`:

```
PRINT6ADDR(rpl_get_parent_ipaddr(dag->preferred_parent));
```

In Contiki-NG, use the function `rpl_parent_get_ipaddr`:

```
LOG_INFO_6ADDR(rpl_parent_get_ipaddr(dag->preferred_parent));
```